# JTable cell spanning more than one column

Tags: java, jtable

I want to have a JTable with N (!=1) columns in which some rows have only one cell that spans the whole N columns.

I've found an example on jguru (http://www.crionics.com/products/opensource/faq/swing_ex/JTableExamples4.html), however I'm yet to understand how it works.

I have also found some other discussions about this pointing to this article ([http://www.swingwiki.org/howto:column_spanning](http://www.swingwiki.org/howto%3acolumn_spanning)), however the link has not been working for some time.

Does anyone have a solution or at least pointers to one?

Comment: If you don't understand the solutions you've found, why would you think any other solution would be easier to understand? It is complex to try to manipulate the default UI of a JTable, so yes, the solution is complex, there is no way to get around that. Maybe someone can provide help if you ask a specific question about the solution you have found.

Answer (score 3):

**Similar Question**

- [JTable column spanning](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/146498/jtable-column-spanning)

**Code-Guru Example**

- http://www.codeguru.com/java/articles/125.shtml
- Java-6 updated sources: http://qoofast.blog76.fc2.com/blog-entry-2.html [(translated)](http://translate.google.ch/translate?hl=de&sl=ja&tl=en&u=http%3A%2F%2Fqoofast.blog76.fc2.com%2Fblog-entry-2.html&anno=2)

  - [ColumnGroup.java](http://blog-imgs-46.fc2.com/q/o/o/qoofast/ColumnGroup.txt)
  - [GroupableTableHeader.java](http://blog-imgs-46.fc2.com/q/o/o/qoofast/GroupableTableHeader.txt)
  - [GroupableTableHeaderUI](http://blog-imgs-46.fc2.com/q/o/o/qoofast/GroupableTableHeaderUI.txt)

**Swing-Wiki Example**

- http://www.swingwiki.org/column_spanning (currenlty not available, [see archived copy](http://web.archive.org/web/20080726035429/http://www.swingwiki.org/howto:column_spanning))