# Is there any way to add a JPanel to a header in a JTable?

Tags: java, swing, jtable, jtableheader

I want to add a JPanel to a column header of the JTable.
Searched a lot, but could not find any answer.
Please help me on this.

Thank you.

Comment: Yes, take a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13213838/how-can-i-set-a-jlabels-background-and-border-the-same-as-a-table-header/13225985#13225985

Comment: As well as this [Q&A](http://stackoverflow.com/q/7137786/230513).

Answer (score 1):

Not directly.

If you want to change the appearance of a cell, then you need to write a custom cell renderer:

- http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/table.html

Answer (score 0):

http://www.coderanch.com/t/339979/GUI/java/Adding-JComboBox-JTable-header. Here's a link similar to your requirement. JComboBox in Jtable header insted of jpanel. This should help you. Agree with paulsm4.